# How to change CPT navigation item's output?

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-post-type

I managed to add my **custom post type to my navigation** using `show_in_nav_menus = true` when registering the post type.

However when adding an item to my **navigation** it is displayed just like any other regular post but I want it to have a slightly **different markup** / output.

I assume there must be a hook / some kind of callback function to do this but I cannot find any.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to take a look into WordPress menu-walker.
What you basically do is create a custom class that defines how your menu should be rendered. There you'll get access to the menu-items properties which you can use for your controlled output.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Comment: Thanks for sharing, unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I am trying to alter how my nav items are displayed in frontend.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I get it... you want your nav-output different. See my updated answer...

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how to describe it properly.. I will try it out later,  thank you for your answer!

Comment: Really helpful article, totally answers my question (y)